# AngularJS with Kendo UI gives "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'each'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm using Kendo in my AngularJS project. I followed the tutorial of the following link: [tutotial](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/).

When I don't have any Kendo elements in my HTML, I don't get an error in the console. But when I use the dropdown example of the tutorial:

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list>
  <option value="1">Thing 1</option>
  <option value="2">Thing 2</option>
  <option value="3">Thing 3</option>
</select>
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'each'
    at Object.e.fn.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/Angular/app/js/kendo.all.min.js:10:846)
    at Object.factories.widget (http://localhost:8080/Angular/app/js/angular-kendo.js:98:27)
    at http://localhost:8080/Angular/app/js/angular-kendo.js:203:36
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:115:185
    at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:33:421)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:37:77
```

Anyone has a clue at what might be the problem?

EDIT:
My includes:

```
<!-- In production use: -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-kendo.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you include jQuery in the project?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with my includes.

Comment: include jQuery before angularjs and try

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think including jQuery before angularjs will solve the problem